# Gradle Module Substitution based on BuildType

Tags: android, gradle

I have a remote maven server setup for hosting artifacts to speed up my gradle build times for an Android project. However, I've been trying to find a way to toggle between using these remote modules, and using local instances of these artifacts by building the `project` targets locally, so that I can test changes to the library projects.

For my project, I have 4 build variants:

- debug
- debugLocal
- qa
- release

In the `dependencies` section of my app-level build.gradle, I would like to be able to declare dependencies like so:

```
implementation 'com.remote:dependency1:x.x.x'
implementation 'com.remote:dependency2:x.x.x'
debugLocalImplementation project(':dependency1')
debugLocalImplementation project(':dependency2')
```

If I attempt to build the debugLocal variant, however, I get dex merge errors as the remote dependency is still included through the `implementation` configuration.

So far, the only way I have found to be able to "toggle off" the remote dependencies is to declare variant-specific configurations for each remote dependency like so:

```
// normal, remote dependencies
debugImplementation 'com.remote:dependency1:x.x.x'
qaImplementation 'com.remote:dependency1:x.x.x'
releaseImplementation 'com.remote:dependency1:x.x.x'
debugImplementation 'com.remote:dependency2:x.x.x'
qaImplementation 'com.remote:dependency2:x.x.x'
releaseImplementation 'com.remote:dependency2:x.x.x'
// debugLocal dependencies
debugLocalImplementation project(':dependency1')
debugLocalImplementation project(':dependency2')
```

As the number of libraries or buildtypes grows, so will this way of declaring/ managing dependencies. Is there a better way to specify to use the local library versions (and exclude the remote libraries) only when we are running our debugLocal buildType?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Implementation" actually builds the variant which you selected in android studio in build variant section.eg:- if you have selected debug then it would be like debugImplemention.

To keep it separate make use of product flavours.

In your case ,you can create

```
productFlavors {

        local {

        }

        remote {

        }
}
```

Create folder local and add you dependency there.
Create folder remote and add you dependency there.

Now when you build using buildvariants you will see localDebug.You also change remoteDebug and run.

You can also create folders based on Buildtypes.Like localDebug and add your libraries.

Comment: So I removed the `debugLocal` buildType and added the productFlavors with exactly one dimension (to suit new AS requirements). This solution does work as I am able to now declare `remoteImplementation` and `localImplementation`, though I do not understand what you mean by creating separate folders. If you can elaborate on that sufficiently or edit your response then I will accept it as a valid answer.

Comment: You can create folders if in case you need keep the libs for local in one folder and remote libs in different folder.I just mentioned thats it.